# How to register global formatter for java.sql.Timestamp in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm exposing the following `Map` via a `@RestController` `Servlet`:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(..);
```

The map then contains a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.

Question: how can I set the output format that `Spring` with `jaxb/jackson` generates for the `Timestamp`? I want to set it globally. I do not want to look the map to detect and reformat the values manually.

The following did not work:

```
@Configuration
public class DateConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        super.addFormatters(registry);
        registry.addFormatterForFieldType(java.sql.Timestamp.class, new Formatter<Timestamp>() {
            @Override
            public String print(Timestamp object, Locale locale) {
                return "my custom format";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The formatter is registered, but never called during serialization to json!

Current result is always like: `2017-07-10T11:06:02.000+0000`. But I'd like to get `2017-07-10 11:06:02` everywhere.

Comment: i think you need the @EnableWebMvc on class level

Comment: I'm using `spring-boot`, and I can see the formatter being registered successfully. So the configuration bean in general works. It just does not affect the serialized Timestamp value.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, date and time fields that are not annotated with @DateTimeFormat are converted from strings using the DateFormat.SHORT style. If you prefer, you can change this by defining your own global format.

Example below:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public FormattingConversionService conversionService() {

        // Use the DefaultFormattingConversionService but do not register defaults
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService(false);

        // Ensure @NumberFormat is still supported
        conversionService.addFormatterForFieldAnnotation(new NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory());

        // Register date conversion with a specific global format
        DateFormatterRegistrar registrar = new DateFormatterRegistrar();
        registrar.setFormatter(new YourTimeStampFormatter());
        registrar.registerFormatters(conversionService);

        return conversionService;
    }
}
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

Comment: Your quote is probably not true, because a `java.sql.Timestamp` is serialized in format `2017-07-10T11:06:02.000+0000`, which is certainly not `DateFormat.SHORT`.

Comment: DateTimeFormat Can be applied to java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.lang.Long, Joda-Time value types; and as of Spring 4 and JDK 8, to JSR-310 java.time types too. So you are right. For `java.sql.Timestamp` it will not use `DateFormat.SHORT` . Perhaps it's not clear enough in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as follows.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.dateFormat(new ISO8601DateFormat()); //or your custom date converter
        }
    };
}
```